# How to display successfully message when i posted comment in face book's wall?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and i am using fbconnect android for connect face book,It is working fine for login and post comment in facebook's wall,but i want to display successful message, when i posted commented in facebook wall.How to do for that.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Toast` to simply show a message: [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html)

Comment: @Vladimit lvanov,I know,where i use Toast?

Comment: make a callback for when you know its gone through, if you use an `AsyncTask` then you would do it onPostExecute()

Comment: i am using fbconnect api for facebook,so where i use Toast?

Comment: use Toast after you call the respective fbconnect api. When you're sure it has been executed.